# Displaying image on page from binary data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I store my image file into the database as binary type ?

if i want to get the image from the database and show it into aspx page.

I have two option

1.To build a handler

2.to use data uri scheme (which i prefer)

what option should i prefer to show the image

Comment: what do you mean by a data uri scheme?

Comment: @Bumble Bee: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: well, in that case i'd go for a HttpHandler as it gives much control over the thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handler is the way to go.  Data URI would only be good if the images were very small, because the user will need to wait for a big page to download with images embedded rather than get the page super-quick then download images concurrently on different connections/threads.

Comment: ohh....you mean to say that i will not get the image if my all the page content is not loaded first and vice versa

Answer (score 3):

Personally I prefer the HTTPHandler approach. It means that should you decide later on that you would prefer to store your binary images in some other fashion then you simply have to update the handler accordingly.

There's a good example of the HTTPHandler approach on this link;

http://www.worldofasp.net/tut/images/Displaying_images_in_ASPNET_using_HttpHandlers_92.aspx

Comment: i mean which option will load my image quickly

Comment: @Saurabh: Without testing I would theorise that the HTTPHandler would be the quickest as the handlers generally respond without all the usual .aspx page state overhead etc. Here's a post which covers the speeds involved in serving images from an HTTPHandler. http://peterkellner.net/2006/09/04/iisaspnetperf/

Comment: "404 ERROR: PAGE NOT FOUND"